# how to merge different tables that have the same structure in mysql?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

I want to merge two or more tables in to one, for example, I have table1.csv and table2.csv, they are from different Mysql server but have the same structure like [A, B, C, datatime].

For different records, if the values of A, B, C are not the same, then directly treat it as different records, if the values of A, B, and C are the same, then only the record with the latest datatime will be kept.

If I first use the program to select which records are useful locally, and then insert them into mysql together, will it be faster than inserting them one by one while selecting?

Comment: May I ask if this is a one-time migration, or is this code intended to be quick and robust for many future usages to come?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This code may need to be used many times, because I have many such tables that need to be merged. The size of each table may be around xG, with millions of records.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easy with a composite unique key over the three field on the table where you want to insert

This query will add a unique key, so you can add the same row again

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`a`, `b`, `c`);
```

This query will append only different records

```
INSERT IGNORE table1 SELECT * FROM table2
```

Comment: Or `LOAD DATA ... IGNORE ...` to load directly from a csv file.